# Denying access to USB ports, but setting up an "escalation" for allowing access on-demand

Tags: windows, usb, group-policy

For Windows 7/10, is there a way to block access to USB ports, but make it so that it could be "authorized" UAC-style by an Administrator, on a case-by-case basis?

I know that I can block the USB ports through GPO, but it'd be a lot of fumbling to address if someone with a legitimate need actually needed to use the USB ports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a Disable group, read enable group, and write enable group for this. With GPOs, you order them so they get processed one after the other. So everybody gets stuffed into the disable group, which gets run first, then the read and write groups get run second, and reverse any of the policies implemented in the disable gpo. You could also "enforce" the read and write GPOs, so the disable one can't override it if it applies.

Then you just have them submit a ticket or what have you and you put them in the group, gpupdate \force on them, and then have them do w/e.

You could also head down there and modify the local group policy to allow it.

Alternatively you could use a third-party application, or copy the data onto the stick yourself for them.

Comment: Oooh, nice! I was trying to avoid 3rd party apps for budget reasons, so I think I'll give your nested GPO approach a shot.

Comment: You're very welcome :) I think you'll find it to be quite acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Symantec Endpoint Protection in your environment, aside of using GPO's SEP can do it natively. SEP can maintain the hosts integrity while Enforcing your removable media policy. Also important is you can set a much more strict policy for machines that are off-net. You could use AD Attributes to assign the policy, which would coincide with your intent to allow admins access. You can also use set allowance for certain types of flash drives like secure encrypted ones.

Not trying to shove it down your throat, but that is a product option at your disposal aside of the GPO method Desthro suggested.